# installing ubuntu 14.04 from usb error

Tags: boot, usb

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 from a gorilla 32gb flash drive, it will install and on reboot if i take out the usb as the computer starts up i get a message telling me to insert the boot media and restart computer, if i leave the usb in, it ask if i want to try ubuntu, install, etc.  i have tried using the livelinux, unetboot, and universal usb installer, and its all the same result.
i have a 40gb drive that i am trying to use on my laptop Toshiba Satellite, i have a 500gb drive as well that came with the laptop but that one has windows 8.1, but i take that hard drive out to put in the 40gb drive, so i know that its not a conflict of operating systems.  is there something that i am doing wrong, or have i forgot something some where?
also when setting it up on the flash drive it asks me to set the persistance, and i set it to 4090mb. but it just will not keep the ubuntu os on reboot.

Comment: Make sure bios is set to legacy mode and  is not in EFI mode and try running boot-repair from your installation live session USB (boot up using the USB to do the repair). Use the 2nd option listed on the following page. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Did you change the boot order to usb first? If so, change to default. I installed linux just 2 weeks ago, didnt have to change anything in the bios nor did I have to disable anything, I just had to tell Windows to boot from the usb, and the only problem I had was I couldnt choose which os to boot, but I got it fixed by fixing the boot loader. In one word, dont change the boot order, just tell your windows to boot from an usb instead. Btw I have Windows 8.1

Comment: @Biu the OP removed the windows hard drive

Comment: @mchid thanks for the link, it helped me get my 40gb hard drive to boot up ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure BIOS is set to legacy mode and is not in EFI mode and try running boot-repair from your installation live session USB (boot up using the USB to do the repair).

Use the 2nd option listed on the following page. http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair